# PowerShell Script to Automate New AD Group Membership

Tags: powershell

Can anyone share ideas for a PowerShell script that will create a new AD global security group and then populate it with all user objects that share a specific attribute?

Comment: Can you perhaps share what you've tried so far? StackOverflow is not a free script-writing service :-)

Comment: Starting points would be the [`New-ADGroup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/new-adgroup), [`Get-ADUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-aduser), and [`Add-ADGroupMember`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/add-adgroupmember) cmdlets.

Answer (score 1):

Use the ActiveDirectory module.

```
$group_name = 'dudez'

New-ADGroup -Name $group_name `
    -GroupCategory Security `
    -GroupScope Global `
    -Path "CN=Users,DC=foo,DC=local" `
    -Description "Members of this group have identified as men."

$dudes = (Get-ADUser -Filter "...").DistinguishedName

Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $group_name -Members $dudes
```

First line creates the group. Second builds the list of users you want in the group. Third line adds the users to the group.

You should be able to modify this to suit your needs.

Comment: I see how it works now. Thank you, that was most helpful.